# LDA analysis, not finding object in data frame despite it being defined

Tags: r, regression, data-science, classification

was doing LDA analysis on some dataset in ISLR library,
I defined a another column as "crime", I ran analysis through glm() and ran it again using lda, however it is not finding the crime variable column which is weird because its the same train dataset I used, here is my code

```
Library(ISLR)
data(Boston)
Boston
nrow(Boston)
ncol(Boston)
colnames(Boston)
summary(Boston)
Boston$crime<-ifelse(Boston$crim>median(Boston$crim),1,0)
split_size=0.7
sample_size=floor(split_size*nrow(Boston))
set.seed(123)
train_indices<-sample(seq_len(nrow(Boston)),size=sample_size)

boston.train<-Boston[train_indices,]
boston.test<-Boston[-train_indices,]
summary(boston.train)
summary(boston.test)

boston.lda<-lda(crime~.,abs(-crime-crim),data=boston.train)
lda.pred<-predict(boston.lda,boston.test)
boston.train
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find `crime` because where `lda` is expecting `data` you provide it with `abs(-crime-crim)`

What is `abs(-crime-crim)` supposed to be doing in the `lda` call?  If you just remove it, the call will work.

By the way, the Boston dataset is in the MASS library, not in the ISLR library.